Getting a printer to exercise the black dye cartridge
My Canon printer has five cartridges, Cyan, Page-black, Yellow, Dye-black and Magenta.
I consider the Cyan, Yellow, Magenta and Dye-black cartridges to be the color cartridges.
Now and then I'll print a nozzle check page.  If a color is light and when there is still ink in cartridge I can sometimes get it going by printing a one page document with squares of just that color - Magenta, Yellow or Cyan. How can I do the same with the small black cartridge (sometimes called the dye based black cartridge)?

To "exercise" the photo-black, cleaning its nozzles:

Create an image that is pure black with a tool such as IrfanView.
Set the image size to about the same ratio as that of the paper you use, e.g., 8,500 x 11,000 pixels for US letter-size.
Print the image as a high-quality photo. You can try using ordinary paper, but if the ink smears, you might need to use (and reuse) a photo paper.

Of course, this works for any color -- yellow sometimes clogs on a printer I use, and I've made a monochrome image for that (i.e., pure red+green, no blue).

Thanks, it is probably the election of high-quality photo paper that is switching to the small dye based ink tank.  At the side of the 1.5 x 1.5 inch black picture, I put the character X.  That character also got printed with dye based ink.

I verify the difference by putting a piece of transparent packing tape over the image.  When pulled off, dye based inks do not come off on the tape but pigmented ink does.  I've used this technique in the past to discover some third party page-black cartridges are filled with dye ink.  Original Canon ink and good third party page black cartridges will partially come off on transparent tape - good enough to make labels with - but black only because again, the dye based inks do not come off on the tape.
